# Gsheet - Automatically send an email using a date & time in a Cell

Tags: date, email, google-sheets, send

I have a simple question : using Gsheet, I have a file where other have actions to perform before a specific date.
Is there a way to send an email automatically generated when the time remaining from that specific date is for example less than 1 day ? And ideally whithout opening Gsheet ?

Am I dreaming ?

Thanks for you reply

I know how to do it for example with app script but I have to trigger it manually to send email.

Comment: [Manage triggers manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#manage_triggers_manually). Set up a time-driven trigger that runs your app script every few hours. In your app script, provide for checking the remaining time until hour X. If hour X has arrived, it will send a letter.